# Proof using the definition of the limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{n^3}{3^n}$ $=0$ using the definition of the limit.

Here is what I have so far:

$\left\lvert{\frac{n^3}{3^n} -0}\right\rvert$ = $\left\lvert{\frac{n^3}{(1+2)^n} }\right\rvert$$<\left\lvert{\frac{n^3}{1+\binom{n}{1}2+\binom{n}{2}2^2+\binom{n}{3}2^3+\binom{n}{4}2^4+\cdots}}\right\rvert$

However, I cannot think of anyway to reduce the above equation so it is less of any $\epsilon$ greater than zero.

Comment: I don't know if you're allowed to do this, but I would first regard the element you're taking the limit of as (proportional to) the third derivative of the exponential, and then proceed. depends on the tools you can make use of, though

Comment: How about proving $\frac{n^3}{3^n}<\frac1n$ for sufficiently large $n$? For example, using $3^{n+1}=3^n+2\cdot3^n$, $(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$ and induction.

Answer (score 2):

I think you did something closely related to the following.

The fifth term in the binomial expansion of $(1+2)^n$ is $\binom{n}{4}2^4$. So for $n\gt 3$ we have 
$(1+2)^n \gt 16\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}$.

Note that if $n\gt 5$ then $n-1\gt n/2$ and $n-2\gt n/2$ and $n-3\ge n/2$. It follows that
$$16\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}\gt 16\cdot\frac{(n)(n/2)(n/2)(n/2)}{4!}=\frac{n^4}{12}.$$

Thus  if $n\ge 5$, then
$$\frac{n^3}{3^n}\lt \frac{12}{n}.$$
Now I think you can finish.

**Remark:** It may have been a strategic mistake to "multiply out." The expression $16\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}$ is easy to think about, while a multiplied out version is less easy.

Comment: You are welcome. There are other ways to do it, starting from your multiplied out expression, but I wanted to make a rhetorical point.

Comment: I had some mistakes. As often happens with my cheap little screen, I mistook a superscript $3$ for a superscript $2$.